# count number of times a function is called with a particular value

Tags: c

I want to create a table with keys from an array. Is there an easy way to do it.

```
int array1[] = {1,5,3,8,9,11};
// table[1]
// table[5]
// table[3]

int count(int a)
{

  //a is one of the values in array. array1[] = {1,5,3,8,9,11};
  // for ex 3. 
  // I have to figure out how many times this function was called with what values  1/5/3/8/9/11 
  table[3]++;
}
```

Comment: create a global array(i.e outside your function count()).Set it to zero(int). And increment the indice values if you encounter a value that's in array1.

Answer (score 0):

A simple code

```
  #include<stdio.h>
int n = 6; //number of elements in array1
int array1[] = {1,3,5,8,9,11};
int *funCount;//Count of elements in array1
int count(int a)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if(a == array1[i])
      break;
  funCount[i]++;
}

int main()
{
  funCount = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
  int i;
  count(1);
  count(3);
  count(5);
  count(8);
  count(9);
  count(11);
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ",funCount[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

This approach is okay if your `array1` is going to be small!
Otherwise I would recommend you to use hashing

Comment: that won't even compile. `n` is not a constant expression.

Comment: obviously it won't compile! What do you expect? Complete code from me?He can set value of 'n' by scanning it!

Comment: I don't expect complete code since I'm not OP. But, this is not C, at least not valid C, and since it is wrong, it's not helpful at all. And while he can set the value of `n` by `scanf()`'ing it, that won't do any good - a global array cannot be of variable length.

Comment: It is C! it is a function in C! what is wrong with it?

Comment: Which line do you think is problematic?

Comment: now it's fine with the dynamic allocation. `int array[n];` doesn't (didn't) work with global arrays, that was problematic.